# displaying the code on CKEditor remove the abbr tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm currently working on a plugin for CKEditor so I followed [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2) tutorial. I've downloaded the full code from the link on the page to use the plugin cause I liked it but I ran into an issue :

when I use the plugin to create and abbr tag, display the code (with the function of CKEDITOR) then switch to normal display; the abbr tag are gone:

this is what I have when I press the "source" button :

```
<abbr title="By The Way">btw</abbr>
```

and this is what I get when I hit the button again :

```
<p>btw</p>
```

so my question is how do you think I can fix this ? and what creat this ? I don't know if this is revelant or not but i'm on windows 7, Firefox 21.0, localhost whith wamp server 2.2 version.

there is the code for the plugin : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2

again I've downloaded the .zip folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 4.1, CKEditor comes with [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) feature. That's why the guide can be a little bit outdated. You need to specify `allowedContent` in command definition to have this working:

```
editor.addCommand( 'abbrDialog',new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'abbrDialog', {
   allowedContent: 'abbr[title]'
} ) );
```

See the official [ACF integration guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf).

Comment: Thank you a lot this is the right thing to do except that since the command i named : addr and not abbrDialog i belive the full line is :

    editor.addCommand( 'abbr', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'abbrDialog',{ allowedContent: 'abbr[title]' 
  } ) );

This on is working and not with abbDialog. Is it correct ?

Comment: If it works, then it's OK ;) I added the link to the answer. Please take a look on this.